# Not able to recursively walk directory in windows using python

Tags: python, windows, os.walk

I am trying to recursively walk a dir in windows using python.

```
def create_folder_structure():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\jira'):
        # print(folder_path)
        print(dirs)

create_folder_structure()
```

The above code works. But not the below one.

```
def create_folder_structure():
    print(folder_path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        print(dirs)

create_folder_structure()
```

and I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\unittest>python unittest.py SMC-11883

C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\jira

C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\unittest>
```

Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Well what is your input and what is the output you'd want to see?

Comment: what is the value of `folder_path` in 2nd scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

def test():
    path = 'C:/Users/xxx/Downloads'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        return dirs
print(test())
```

Comment: This is windows machine. The path should contain backslashes.

Comment: The problem was that I was reading folder_path value from a text file and the newline character was present at the end. It works fine once I remove the newline character. Thanks w1n5rx for your response.

Comment: @AhteshamAkhtar, in general a path on Windows should use backslashes. But it's ok to use forward slash if you know the path will be immediately consumed by a Windows file-system API such as `FindFirstFile`. Either way, the NT runtime library has to convert the path to a form that the NT kernel understands, e.g. `\??\C:\Users\xxx\Downloads`. In this case `\??\C:` is an object link in the kernel's `\??` virtual DOS device directory. The real path after resolving links is something like `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\xxx\Downloads`.

Comment: @w1n5rx, you're returning on the first iteration of a `for` loop.